# Try Catch Statement doesn't work on Simulator (but works on iPhone!!!)

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios-simulator, try-catch, nsexception

I have an Exception catching statement in my code, like the following:

```
@try {
      for(NSDictionary* s in users)
      {
           do something ....
      }
 }
 @catch (NSException * exception) {
      NSLog(@"APIRequesetBase readUserInfo: Caught %@: %@", [exception name], [exception reason]);
 }
 @finally {

 }
```

So this try statement works perfectly on the iphone device, it can catch the exception.
However, on simulator, it can never catch the exception. It just crashes!!

I also try other simple try catch statement to test it,
and the simulator can never catch the exception. It just simply crashes!!

This issue is so strange.
Does anyone have this issue before?

Or is it because of the setting?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug that will be fixed in a future release.

Comment: Since you're sitting at the source: Cannot you convince management at Apple that developers would love them for opening up radar? It would be **so helpful** to browse known issues. You could have posted a link to the report in this answer, for example.

Comment: By the way, I liked your WWDC presentation (as usual)! Just don't let them make it an all beginners event.

Comment: Is this still a known issue? A year later? For I am running into exactly the same problem, but if its a known issue still than I will not post a new question about it.

Comment: I should so have added the @bbum to that last post, but it wont let me edit anymore.

Comment: Have you tested it on the NDA'd tools [that we can't discuss here]?  If so, then file a bug and take the question to the deforums.